# using oop in c programming

Tags: c, oop

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

I am doing some practicing on using some object-oriented style in C. As I want to do this for some of our larger projects.

However, in my code below I have a parent structure car and a child sports_cars. However, all the commom attibutes or the car struct will be present in the child structures.

There is one question I have and that is the init and destory functions. As they are commom I want my child structures to heritant the init and the destroy. But I think I am doing it wrong.

```
car->init = init_car;
```

As I have the init function pointer pointing to init_car, doesn't look right to me.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tag_car car_t;
struct tag_car {
    size_t wheels;
    char *name;

    void (*init)(void *self);
    void (*destroy)(void *self);
    size_t (*wheels_get)(void *self);
    void (*wheels_set)(void *self, size_t num_wheels);
};

typedef struct tag_sports sports_t;
struct tag_sports {
    car_t base_car;

    size_t top_speed;
    size_t (*top_speed_get)(void *self);
    void (*top_speed_set)(void *self, size_t max_top_speed);
};

void destroy_car(void *self)
{
    car_t *car = self;

    free(car);
}

void init_car(void *self)
{
    car_t *car = car;

    car->wheels = 4;
    car->name = NULL;

    car->init = init_car;
    car->destroy = destroy_car;

}

size_t wheels_count_get(void *self)
{
    car_t *car = self;

    return car->wheels;
}

void wheels_count_set(void *self, size_t num_wheels)
{
    car_t *car = self;

    car->wheels = num_wheels;
}

size_t sports_top_speed_get(void *self)
{
    sports_t *sports_car = self;

    return sports_car->top_speed;
}

void sports_top_speed_set(void *self, size_t max_top_speed)
{
    sports_t *sports_car = self;

    sports_car->top_speed = max_top_speed;
}

sports_t* init_sports()
{
    sports_t *sports_car = malloc(sizeof(sports_t));

    /* Parent struct */
    sports_car->base_car.init = init_car; 
    sports_car->base_car.destroy = destroy_car;
    sports_car->base_car.wheels_get = wheels_count_get;
    sports_car->base_car.wheels_set = wheels_count_set;

    /* Child struct */
    sports_car->top_speed_set = sports_top_speed_set;
    sports_car->top_speed_get = sports_top_speed_get;

    return sports_car;
}

int main(void)
{
    sports_t *farreri = init_sports();
    sports_t *lamborghini = init_sports();

    farreri->base_car.wheels_set(farreri, 10);
    farreri->top_speed_set(farreri, 240);

    printf("farreri has wheel count [ %ld ]\n", farreri->base_car.wheels_get(farreri));
    printf("Farreri has a top speed [ %ld ]\n", farreri->top_speed_get(farreri));

    lamborghini->base_car.wheels_set(lamborghini, 6);
    lamborghini->top_speed_set(lamborghini, 220);

    printf("lamborghini has wheel count [ %ld ]\n", lamborghini->base_car.wheels_get(lamborghini));
    printf("Lamborghini has a top speed [ %ld ]\n", lamborghini->top_speed_get(lamborghini));

    farreri->base_car.destroy(farreri);
    lamborghini->base_car.destroy(lamborghini);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't implemented *polymorphism* correctly, a key oop feature.  You now leave it up to the client code to use *base_car* but that cannot work when you pass a lamborghini* to a function that takes a car*.  An extra level of indirection is needed, look at how v-tables are used in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `init_car` the lines

```
car->init = init_car;
car->destroy = destroy_car;
```

shouldn't be present. You're mixing the construction behavior with initialization. In C++ the constructor is responsible for doing both; if you want to simulate the same behavior, you should expose allocation interface (e.g., call it `construct`) which will allocate the memory (your `malloc` and also setting the object "methods"  to the appropriate functions) and initialization interface (which will do the init stuff: `car->wheels = 4;    car->name = NULL;`). The allocation method can call the initialization method to achieve the C++ behavior. You'll have something like this:

```
void init_car(void *self)
{
    car_t *car = self;

    car->wheels = 4;
    car->name = NULL;
}

sports_t* construct()
{
    sports_t *sports_car = malloc(sizeof(sports_t));

    /* Set the methods */
    sports_car->base_car.init = init_car; 
    sports_car->base_car.destroy = destroy_car;
    sports_car->base_car.wheels_get = wheels_count_get;
    sports_car->base_car.wheels_set = wheels_count_set;

    /* initialize the object */
    sports_car->base_car.init();

    return sports_car;
 }

int main(void)
{
    /* construct and init the objects */
    sports_t *ferrari = construct();
    sports_t *lamborghini = construct();

    /* do your manipulations */

    /* destroy the objects */
    ferrari->base_car.destroy(farreri);
    lamborghini->base_car.destroy(lamborghini);

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want the construction to init the object, just don't invoke the initialization from `construct`, invoke it after the construction by calling `sports_car->base_car.init`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointer to structure wich contains pointers to functions - just like [hidden] vtable in C++. Also, `car_t *car = car;` is incorrect, i suppose you've meant 'self'